# Регулярное выражение в ссылке html

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, html

Здравствуйте, есть такой код html:

```
<td class="b-head-userinfo__exit"><a class="b-head-userinfo__link" href="http://сайт.ru/passport?mode=logout&yu=9135152641405399383">Выход</a></td>
```

Мне нужно сделать автоматический переход по этой сслыке.
В c# написал переход по ссылке так (работает):

```
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://сайт.ru/passport?mode=logout&yu=9135152641405399383", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Помогите цифровое значение 9135152641405399383 заменить на регулярное выражение, так как числа в ссылке постоянно меняются.

Пробовал подставить вместо 9135152641405399383 - [0-9] - не работает.

Comment: Я таки не понял шо вы в итоге хотите. Извлечь со страницы все ссылки вида `http://сайт.ru/passport?mode=logout&yu=ЛЮБОЕ_ЧИСЛО`?

Comment: Та нет. Я просто хочу шоб автоматически прога делала переход по динамической ссылке на сайте. моежт через регулярное выражение, а может по другому как-то.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать HtmlAgilityPack для этих целей. Подробнее в Гугл.

Comment: `WebBrowser` (это у вас, кстати, WinForms или WPF?) даёт доступ к DOM. Для WPF это делается через свойство `Document` ([отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12963485/276994)).